# Can't write user_id from users table into posts table in database

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to write post, and that post have content, adress and user_id in database. With content and adress I had no problem, but for user_id there is always 0 in database, no metter whitch user write post.
[database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxJ7q.png)

Here is my code:
Frontend- I get user data from context. And when I console.log(user.result[0].id) I get user_id (for example 155).

```
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
   
    const addPost = async () => {
        console.log(user);
        await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/CreateAds', {
            user_id: user.result[0].id,
            content: formValues.content,
            adress: formValues.adress
```

Backend:

```
app.post('/CreateAds', (req, res) => {
    const user_id=req.body.user_id;
    const content = req.body.content;
    const adress = req.body.adress;
    db.query("INSERT INTO posts(user_id,content,adress) VALUES (?,?,?)", [user_id, content, adress],
```